# Windows tiling doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, tiling

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5. Following the manual from https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-tiled.html neither of two methods of horizontal window tiling works. Dragging window's title bar works only for maximizing it, not tiling.

I don't recall installing any applications, which could affect this behavior. I have Gnome Tweaks installed, but I don't see an option for tiling there. Any clues how to restore this functionality? Is it broken in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I use [ShellTile Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/) which works great and should do what you're asking for.

Comment: @pLumo I installed gTile https://github.com/gTile/gTile, which seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Gnome Tweaks" again, on the Windows tab. There is an option "Edge Tiling" that needs to be on to enable left/right tiling by dragging to the edge of the screen. Alternatively, enable the setting with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling true
```

Then check that your keybindings for tiling are correctly assigned. You can reset to the default with the following two terminal commands:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right
```

Comment: No  "Edge Tiling" on my system: https://imgur.com/665MXHF

Comment: I added a command to enable Edge Tiling, please check.

Comment: I tried and the result is negative. My system is up to date.